# How i get a selected value from select drop down list and pass it to a method and then print (lightning)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm trying to printing the selected value from dropdown list in lightning
     but when i select a value not responding

```
 my component :

   <lightning:select name="select" label="BookFair Accounts" required="true" messageWhenValueMissing="Did you forget to select a BookFair?" class="select-auto-width" aura:id="InputSelectDynamic" onchange="{!c.doGetAccounts}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="acc" >
        <option value="{!acc.Name}">{!acc.Name}</option>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select><br/>
```

component controller for getting drop down list:

```
doGetAccounts: function(component) {
var action = component.get('c.getAccounts');
var self = this;
action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
 component.set('v.accounts', actionResult.getReturnValue());
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

},

how can i get the selected value

Comment: can you please post the code for action "getAccountsOppsList".

Comment: @praveen thanks for giving the quick response .please find the my updated post

Answer (score 1):

You can access the value by the following code

```
component.find('InputSelectDynamic').get("v.value");
```

Hope this helps.